# mocking related objects using fflib

Tags: apex, fflib

I am trying to add records to `Opportunity.OpportunityLineItems`; however, I got an error that that field is read-only. I tried to mock that field via fflib, code as follows:

```
fflib_ApexMocks mocks = new fflib_ApexMocks();

Opportunity opportunityMock1 = new Opportunity(Id = fflib_IDGenerator.generate(Opportunity.SObjectType));

mocks.startStubbing();
mocks.when(opportunityMock1.OpportunityLineItems).thenReturn(new List<OpportunityLineItem>{
        new OpportunityLineItem(Id = fflib_IDGenerator.generate(OpportunityLineItem.SObjectType)),
        new OpportunityLineItem(Id = fflib_IDGenerator.generate(OpportunityLineItem.SObjectType))
});
mocks.stopStubbing();
```

After mocking the opportunity `opportunityMock1.OpportunityLineItems` it returns null. Do you know what am I doing wrong? or maybe a different way to add items to `opportunityMock1.OpportunityLineItems`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I learnt that the way to mock a related list of an object in fflib is by using the method `fflib_ApexMocksUtils.makeRelationship`.

Solution:

```
fflib_ApexMocks mocks = new fflib_ApexMocks();

Opportunity opportunityMock1 = new Opportunity(Id = fflib_IDGenerator.generate(Opportunity.SObjectType));

List<Opportunity> opportunitiesWithProductsMock = (List<Opportunity>) fflib_ApexMocksUtils.makeRelationship(
        List<Opportunity>.class,
        new List<Opportunity>{
                opportunityMock1
        },
        OpportunityLineItem.OpportunityId,
        new List<List<OpportunityLineItem>>{
                new List<OpportunityLineItem>{
                        new OpportunityLineItem(Id = fflib_IDGenerator.generate(OpportunityLineItem.SObjectType)),
                        new OpportunityLineItem(Id = fflib_IDGenerator.generate(OpportunityLineItem.SObjectType))
                }
        }
);
```

Comment: this is correct but I found the syntax messy and switched to using [SObject Fabricator](https://github.com/mattaddy/SObjectFabricator) and never looked back - syntax so much clearer

Comment: I had a look to the repo, it is great!. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Pro tip: in sfab, relationship names are case sensitive